# How to load millions(10 millions) byte array to memory in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application, the requirement is we need to load millions of byte array to memory to supply these to one personal sdk method which takes argument as IEnumerable. The problem is to convert such a huge amount of files into bytes arrays(each file to byte[]).There are about 10 million such files. These takes lots of time and memory to load. so how to accomplish this task. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "These takes lots of time and memory to load" - so which is the bigger concern?  Making it faster or taking less memory?  Usually those two are inversely related.

Comment: You should probably post the code that loads the files.  If the data is static (doesn't change by request) then you could load it async on app startup.

Comment: If there are millions of files most likely this person won't use them all at one time, so maybe you can load them on demnad.

Comment: I was also thinking about this, but these file 10 million take much time to convert to byte[] for each file. Also these files may increase in real time.

Comment: So, you're saying that you have an SDK method which wants you to send an IEnumerable, where each item is a bytearray of a file, and you have over 10 million files? This sounds ridiculous, unless the files are infinitesimal, your RAM is going to cry, and there's no way you're going to do it quickly.

Comment: @Tobberoth, i just want to make the process fast.

Comment: Your title is asking how to load X number of files in memory. What have you tried? See how big the total number of files are and get a server that has that much ram. If you don't have that much ram, see how much the files are in compressed format. Write a function to load everything on servlet init in e.g. a HashMap. You can also try using a ramdisk to see how performance is affected.

Answer (score 7):

This is very probably not a good idea.

It's probably best to save your data in files, load a file in memory when you need it, and keep a cache of the n most recently used files. That way you can manage the amount of memory you consume and your server won't be bogged down by what you are doing.

You didn't mention how large the files are, BTW, but file systems are pretty fast now and in combination with that cache, performance will probably be acceptable. I would test this scenario before trying anything funny in-memory.

Comment: Each file is of 2kb. The sdk needs all these with each in byte[] in IEnumerable at once to yield results. Cant alter sdk. I have 10 million files.

Comment: That sounds like a bad SDK to me, OR it was never intended to be used this way to begin with. My advice would be not to go ahead with this, it will never work properly.

Comment: +1. But "very probably not a good idea" should be "almost certainly a really bad idea."

Answer (score 4):

10 million files of 2 KB each is 20 gigabytes of data. Even if it was in a single file it'd take on the order of three minutes to load at the typical disk transfer speed of 100 megabytes per second. But because you're opening 10 million individual files it's going to take a lot longer.

If those 10 million files are in a single directory it's going to take even longer. NTFS does not perform well when you have that many files in a single directory.

If the files are in a single directory, I'd suggest splitting them up. You're better off having fewer than 10,000 files (and preferably fewer than 1,000) files in a single directory. Create a directory hierarchy to hold the files.

That still leaves you with having to open 10 million individual files. If the data doesn't change often, you should create a single binary file that contains the file names and the associated data. You'd have to recreate that file every time one of the constituent files changes, but you already have to restart your application if one of the files changes.

But all told, I really don't understand why you want to load all this data into memory. If your Web app is going to squirt this down the pipe to some requesting application, the data transfer time will be, at best, the same speed as reading the data from a file. So you're better off having something that reads the data from the file and streams it to the requesting application.

If your application requires that this 20 GB be in memory so that you can send it to the requesting app, then there's probably something seriously wrong with your application design.

One more thing: as I recall, IIS recycles processes from time to time. If your Web app is idle for a long period, then IIS might very well flush it from memory. So the next time somebody makes a request to your application, it will have to reload the data. If you want the data to truly be persistent, you probably want a Windows service that will load the data and keep it in memory. The Web app can query the service for the data when it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

Foreseeable issues:

- Performance: Sequential serialization of a large amount of files can be time consuming.
- RAM: Payload total size may request critical amounts of memory.

Possible solutions:

- Distribute the serialization task. Spawn worker threads, set [processor affinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each in order to evenly distribute workload. Your disk/repository I/O will probably be the bottleneck.
- Implement paging. Don't try to load everything in memory. Serialize blocks on demand. As long as your serialization is faster that the required physical network bandwidth, there'll be no 'buffer underrun' situations - in this case, an empty channel waiting for server to answer. That way your process may even start replying faster than if you tried to do full serialization before starting transmitting.
- Cache as much as you want, as little as you can. Don't redo costly work.

That said...

...I completely agree with Roy Dictus and the others - seems a very bad model to me.